# angular 2 - asynchrone issue

Tags: asynchronous, angular, ionic2

I have a very simple Typescript script (ionic2 and angular2) that add an authentication header before an HTTP call. Here is the idea (simplified code):

```
function CreateAuthorization(){
    this.header.append('tests' : 'test')

    Storage.retrieve('Auth').then(data){
        this.header.append('authorization' : data.token)
    }

}


function customHttp(url){
    CreateAuthorization();
    Http.get(url, this.header);
}
```

In my Request header, I have  'test' = 'test' but I do NOT have 'authorization' = 'MyToken'.

How can I make in sort to "wait" for the header to be set in Storage.retrieve('Auth') ?

I know that I can use a setTimeout() but I don't like this dirty workaround.

The solution could be an observable/promise but I don't really master those things.

Any help would be very appreciated :)

Geoffrey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your `CreateAuthorization` method is asynchronous. I would try something like that leveraging promise chaining to be notified when the `Authorization` header is actually added:

```
createAuthorization() {
  this.header.append('tests' : 'test');

  return Storage.retrieve('Auth').then(data){
    this.header.append('authorization', data.token);
    return true;
  }
}

customHttp(url) {
  this.createAuthorization().then(() => {
    this.http.get(url, { headers: this.header });
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. But if createAuthorization() is a premise, isn't is suppose to use resolve(x) instead of return ?

Comment: You're welcome! In fact, you can leverage promise chaining. If you return a raw value in the `then` (the first one here), it will be automatically wrapped into a resolved promise. In fact it's a shortcut ;-)